# How to determine if there's a run of characters in an array?

Tags: java, android, arrays, integer

Say we have an array:

```
array = [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1];
```

And we want to find a "run" of duplicate numbers where there are at least three in a row.  In this case, it would be the set of 0, 0, 0, and 1, 1, 1.

How can I determine which indices contain the "runs" of three or more?

Comment: Please provide a sample output also. It's not clear what kind of output you want.

Comment: Loop through the array, count the number of things you find in a row, if the count is 3 or more, there's your run.

Comment: What would happen in the case 0,0,0,0? Is that two adjoint runs of three or one of four? This question is badly posed.

Comment: What code have you tried so far? Perhaps not the best solution, but you could make a `run` class that contains variables for start/end index and the value. Then create `ArrayList<run>` and add a new `run` object when you find 3+ in a row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run class to hold information for a run

```
class Run {
    int first,last,length,value;
    public Run(int value, int first, int last){
        this.value = value;
        this.first = first;
        this.last = last;
        length = last - first + 1;
    }
    public int value(){return value;}
    public int first(){return first;}
    public int last(){return last;}
    public int length(){return length;}
}
```

---

Example test code

```
int[] array = new int[]{1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1};
ArrayList<Run> runs = new ArrayList<Run>();
for(int i=0; i<array.length-2; i++){
    if(array[i+1]==array[i]){
        int j = i + 1;
        int count = 2;
        while(array[j+1] == array[i] && j<array.length - 1){
            count++;
            j++;
        }
        if(count>2){
            runs.add(new Run(array[i], i, j));
        }
        i = j;
    }
}
for(Run r : runs){
    System.out.println("There is a run of " + r.length() + 
            " " + r.value() + "'s from index " + r.first() + 
            " to " + r.last() + ".");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. create a

   `HashMap<Integer, Integer> result = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();`
2. iterate your array store the array-value as key and the count of the value as value in the hashmap:

   `for (int i: arrayToCount) {
          Integer count = result.get(i);
          if (count == null)
             result.put(i, new Integer(1));
          else
             result.put(i, new Integer(count+1));
       }`
3. Iterate the HashMap and return your values.

Answer (score 0):

```
package algorithms;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class CountOfDupes {
 HashMap<Integer, Integer> myMap = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();

void incrementDupeCounter(int[] arr){
    int curVal;
    for (int rec : arr){
        if (myMap.containsKey(rec)) {
            curVal = myMap.get(rec);
            myMap.put(rec, curVal + 1);
        } else {
            myMap.put(rec, 1);
        } 
    }
}

void printRunEntries(){
    for (HashMap.Entry<Integer, Integer> entry : myMap.entrySet()) {
        if (entry.getValue() >= 3){
            System.out.println(entry.getKey() + "/" + entry.getValue());
        }
    }
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    int arr[] = {1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1};

    CountOfDupes cd = new CountOfDupes();
    cd.incrementDupeCounter(arr);
    cd.printRunEntries();
}
```

}